# Trouble coneccting Pc with Android 2.1 mobile for the Bluetooth Chat example

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I'm new to programming Android devices. I'm making an school project which involves an Android (Mini-Xperia pro with Android 2.1) and bluetooth communication with a device.
I'm trying to go step by step to undesrstand all of the programming stuff and to learn all I can.

I've got an Bluetooth adapter for the PC, I'm working with Windows XP so I only connect it and it's already installed.

Well, I'm working over the Bluetooth Chat sample that comes with the SDK and I've already changed the UUID to:

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
```

With my mobile I entered to settings and made my device paired to my Pc (it says paired but with out conection).

But I don't know what I'm doing wrong cause I open the Bluetooth chat application on my mobile, try to connect to my pc and it says "unable to connect device".

After a lot of tries, it connects to transmit from the pc to the phone:
  A

AT

And the connection is lost (this takes less than 2 seconds!!)

Can anyone help me please tell me what am I doing wrong or what's the problem??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the ConnectThread code to the following: Note the change code which creates the socket.

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        Method m = null;
        try {
            m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", 
                                                    new Class[] {int.class});
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        try {
            tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }
```

Comment: Hi again. I'm a little confused. I've got a bluetooth adapter which is really very small and very cheap, but I've read that I need a bluetooth wich has already serial communication, so I don't know if I've to buy it or if there is a second way to make the usb adapter work like a serial port maybe using a max232 or something like that cause the bluetooth that I need for my final application (bluesmirf attached to an android card here in Mexico is about $990 pesos (like 80 dollars) =S

Answer (score 0):

you need to run some application like a hyper-terminal on the PC side over the Bluetooth Serial COM port to which the android application is connecting.